# Replace CakePHP route from Plugin to be another route

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.4

I am using a CakePHP plugin for user management, which specifies a route for an Access Denied page.

```
Router::connect('/accessDenied', array('plugin' => 'usermgmt', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'accessDenied'));
```

In my main Cake app, I'd like to 'override' this route to use my own controller.

I don't want to modify the plugin...as it will cause future code maintenance when the plugin is updated.

Is there a way I can replace a plugin's route with my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Router::promote()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Router.html#_promote):

> **Router::promote()**
>   Promote a route (by default, the last one added) to the beginning of the list

If I understood your question correctly, you wanted to overwrite just one route. In your `app/Config/routes.php`, add the overridden route and a promote after `CakePlugin::routes();`

```
//.... your routes....

//Here the plugin routes being loaded
CakePlugin::routes();

//Overwrite route:
Router::connect('/accessDenied', array('plugin' => 'usermgmt', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'accessDenied'));
Router::promote(); //and promote it
```

That should do the trick. Promote does nothing but move the last route to top. In CakePHP, routing works as first-come-first-served basis (if you [check the source closely](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Router.html#346) it's an array), so promoting will move your last defined route to top and hence overwrite the route defined in the plugin.

**Edit**

If you do not like promoting, you can also define the route *before* `CakePlugin::routes()`. That should do the trick as well.

Comment: The info in your edit did the trick for me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Simply just don't load the plugin with routes and use your own in app/Config/routes.php

```
CakePlugin::load('UserManagement', array('bootstrap' =>  true, 'routes' => false);
```

Comment: The plugin loads 52 routes, and if possible I would like to avoid redefining 51 of them to avoid 1.